# Using alpha-numeric keys to JOIN tables and in WHERE conditions

Tags: php, sql, performance, join, where-clause

So I have this database where many tables have a `primary key` which is an `auto-increment numeric ID` called `record_id` and a `surrogate unique hash field` called `record_hash` `(alpha-numberic 16 chars)`

I see that in many places, the `JOINS` and `WHERE` conditions are written on the `record_hash`. My question is - will this is be slower then the record_id field. Are there differences in `JOIN` only or for both `JOIN and WHERE`?

Comment: For InnoDB storage engine - every single lookup (JOIN, WHERE etc.) will be faster when performed with primary key, compared to unique key. For engines such as TokuDB, if the unique key is also clustering index - I *think* that performance will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Speed is really determined both by the queries and the indexes on a table.  If there are similiar indexes on both columns that are used in queries, then performance will be similiar.  The only minor difference is that the numeric id will be smaller, which will be a bit quicker to read and compare.

In general, when designing a database a single unique id is all you need.  A record hash just adds unessecary overhead.  I would stick to the id whenever possible.

Comment: What you wrote isn't true in all cases, especially in case where you use InnoDB. PK vs surrogate = PK wins, by a huge margin when it comes to read performance. There are tons of articles on InnoDB and clustering, I suggest you read them.

Comment: @N.B.  Why do you think this is InnoDB?  Its just tagged as sql so I gave a generic answer.

Comment: My apologies, it was me wrongly assuming that this is tagged mysql. However, you are correct in what you said, except in cases where primary key is used for clustering and surrogate isn't because that changes the low-level implementation on how records are read - using 1 I/O compared to using 2 I/Os is not a marginal difference sadly.

Comment: @N.B. guys, I should be the one to apologize. I had marked it as sql hoping to get a broader audience. In fact I am using InnoDB. Both your comments have given me good insight.

Comment: I have an option to write a function that fetches the record_id given a record_hash which can then be used in the queries. It is an additional query...not sure if that will help reduce or increase the problem...

Comment: @N.B.  You are correct about the clustered key which is why I said it is determined by the indexes on the table.  You also happen to be a physic and realized this is InnoDB :)  I would go ahead and post your comment dealing with InnoDB as an answer.

Comment: @UndefinedVariable  That function probably would just slow things down.  I would runa few tests on your system though and compare the speed difference.

Comment: Unless you use primary key directly, you're going to end up with an additional I/O per join/where. To "feel" the difference, lower `innodb_buffer_pool` to a small value to force InnoDB to use HDD completely and compare what happens when you query via surrogate compared to PK.